# BizTalk deployment errors

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I got the following errors when I deployed my BizTalk project.

> Error  1   Failed to update binding information.
>       Could not change the bindings for orchestration 'BizTalk_Server_test.BizTalk_Orchestration1,BizTalk Server test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=56064b11c189a7aa' as one or more instances of the orchestration still exist.

---

> Error  2   Failed to add resource(s). 
>       Change requests failed for some resources. BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type change request. Failed to update binding information. Could not change the bindings for orchestration 'BizTalk_Server_test.BizTalk_Orchestration1,BizTalk Server test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=56064b11c189a7aa' as one or more instances of the orchestration still exist.

I tried to re-build the orchestration and restart the server, I still got these errors. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to **full stop** the orchestration then delete the project.
build solution and deploy it again.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to perform a **Full Stop** of the application, as this can cause you to lose binding information if you have customised your bindings without re-exporting them.

As the error message says, you need to **terminate all** Service and/or Messaging instances relating to the application.

Go to your BizTalk Group page in BizTalk Administrator, click the "Suspended Instances" link, then right-click and select "Teminate instances" from the pop-up menu.

You should now be able to redeploy your BizTalk project.  Don't forget to **restart** any associated Host Instances, or you wont see your changes at runtime.

Comment: I've never come across the bindings being lost by doing a full stop of a BizTalk application.  Backing up the bindings before doing a deploy is good practice however as your deployment may overwrite them or load them from a cached version on disk. Noting that passwords will NOT be included in the export of bindings so if you do re-import that you will have to re-enter the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following steps:

1. Go to your BizTalk Group page in BizTalk Administrator,
2. click the "Suspended Instances" link
3. then right-click and select "Teminate instances" from the pop-up menu.

You should now be able to redeploy your BizTalk project. Don't forget to restart any associated Host Instances or you won't see your changes at runtime.